# Initialize hash elements to 0

Tags: perl, hashcode, perl-data-structures

I declare a hash in Perl by doing this:

```
my %hash = ();
```

I go on adding elements to the hashes. Sometimes, `$hash{$x}` is not defined, meaning it probably is `null`. So when I try to print it, I do not get anything. I expect to see a `0` in case that entry `$x` is not defined. Can someone tell me how do I do this? How do I initialize hash elements to `0` initially?

Comment: Declaring a hash as `= ()` is redundant.

Comment: Please show your Perl code so that we can help you properly

Answer (score 6):

Instead of trying to set a default value, you can print a default value when you encounter an undefined value by using the [defined-or operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or), `//` (works for Perl 5.10 and higher).

In this example, when you print your hash elements, you either print the element, or if it is not defined, `0`:

```
use 5.010;

say $hash{$x} // 0;
```

Comment: In earlier versions of perl `| 0` can work, but will replace an empty string with a zero.

Comment: @Sobrique Shouldn't that be `|| 0`?

Comment: Ideally yes, although in this limited example it doesn't make much difference.  bitwise or of `undef | 0` evaluates to `0` too :).  Can also do `||=` or `//=` to assign as well. `print $hash{$key} //= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such of thing as default value for non defined hash key

the correct way to manipulate hash is to test if your key is defined, with 'defined' function (see [perl defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html))

```
[~]=> perl -e '%x = (a=>1, c=>5); for (a..d) { print "$_ => "  . (defined $x{$_} ? $x{$_} :0) . "\n"  }'
a => 1
b => 0
c => 5
d => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that one doesn't test if a key is defined, but if a key exists using the exists key word. One tests to see if the value is defined with the defined keyword.

```
print "Exists\n"    if exists $hash{$key};
print "Defined\n"   if defined $hash{$key};
print "True\n"      if $hash{$key};
```

The first tests if the key exists,
 the 2nd if the value is defined and
 the 3rd if the value returns a true value.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to initialise the hash.

```
my %hash = ();
@hash{@keys} = (0) x @keys;
```

This will create a hash, give it an element for each key and then set the values to an array of 0's as long as the key array.